# Single Page App without URL

Tags: angularjs, url, single-page-application

I'm joining a team that is currently working on a single page app. It is written with AngularJS, but it doesn't matter for the topic.

The App is so complex (many independant views with complex different states within each) that they completly removed the router (well, excerpt the default route).

I'm googling around but I can see no example of webapp that is not trying to work properly with URLs. Is there any risk of not using any URL, beyond the fact that "it is not the elegant way" ?

EDIT : ui-router does not fit, because of this issue : https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/90

Comment: Funny they removed the router because it became too complex. A router should solve the complexitiy by moving features into their own module.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to look into something like UI-Router which works on states.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

I can't imagine any significant issues with your app if you do it this way, but I can see massively bloated controllers and code to try and get around any issues you find.

Comment: No, this is not the question. The app is too complex for ui-router, it has been tried but abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

as @Varedis said, you can use ui-router, but to answer your actual question, consider the use case for urls.

If you have only one url, there's only one entry point into your app. This can be annoying if the user expects to be able to quickly go to a certain area (state) within your app. Only one url means that the user can't bookmark, directly go to, or find with a search engine, any specific part of your application.

You can use other mechanisms like cookies or LocalStorage to keep track of state, but these are less user-visible.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the project and i founded a month ago, ui-router-extras which provide parralel states but it can't instiante more than [one state instance](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/90).

Is there another solution to do that ?